# Can't remove element with jquery's remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm making a greasemonkey script for this website: http://tinyurl.com/websiteasdasd and I want to remove the element `rodape-ao-vivo`, problem is that doing `$("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();` is not working, however, if I do something like

```
setInterval(function() {
        $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
    }, 1000);
```

it works just fine, so I'm basically asking you to help me understand what's going on here. Maybe it's just a small stupid thing but I'm sleepless and really want to get this done.

Comment: You want to delete it on load?

Comment: $(function() { $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove(); });

Comment: That element is being appended to the document by a script so attempting to remove it before that script has added it is pointless.

Comment: @Alvaro I'm using `window.addEventListener("load", boot(), false);` and `boot()` is just the remove thing. Oh and also using `run-at          document-start` which I guess is part of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that all the elements gets loaded before your use them.So wrap your code inside function which will ensure your elements has been attached to `DOM`

```
$("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove(); //will probably will give you an error.

$(function() {
    $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
}
```

Or ,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
})
```

Or,

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
});
```

Or,

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
}
```

But when you do ,

```
setInterval(function() {
        $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
}, 1000);
```

This will give an element time to get load in your `DOM`.So It working fine.But instead of using setInterval you can use function listed above

Answer (score 2):

This DIV is dynamically generated by script, to remove it, you need to wait until this element is availabe in DOM, e.g if for some reason other answers don't work: {or use DOM ready handler}

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if ($("#rodape-ao-vivo").length) {
            $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps you are trying to remove the element before it's created? (The delay helps because in that time the element gets created and you can remove it)

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to remove the element before it even exists. Adding one second delay gives the browser enough time to render the element, so you can remove it then. But it's not guaranteed to work, because one second may not be enough to render that element (slow connection, for example).

So you should make sure the document is ready, jQuery's way to do this is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
});
```

Or you can wait for the whole document to load:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your doing this when the page is loading then wrap your code use document.ready();

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#rodape-ao-vivo").remove();});
```